# Is it possible to get AMD APP Profiler working with C#/Cloo?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, profiler, amd-processor, cloo

Does anyone know how/if it's possible to get AMD APP Profiler working on C# projects using the Cloo opencl library? I can run `sprofile` on my .NET app but even though it runs correctly no results are outputted.

---

**Edit:** Heh, it does work I just had some dodgy OpenCL code causing the display driver the crash. Just run `sprofile` from the command line like it describes in the help files then open it using the panel in VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, the recommended method for using APP Profiler on a C# application is to use the command line version (sprofile.exe), and then import the results into the Visual Studio plugin after the fact.

The upcoming CodeXL product (currently in public beta) will allow you to profile a C# application directly from the standalone UI.  See http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/CodeXL/pages/default.aspx for more information on CodeXL.

Chris

Comment: Sounds awesome! Can't wait to get my hands on it, should speed up my workflow significantly.